# Onlyoffice community server installaton

Tags: onlyoffice

I am installing onlyoffice community server on my machine windows 10.

I downloaded exe file from here - https://www.onlyoffice.com/download.aspx

I get a warning  message with below screen:

[image]

Next screen is for mysql configuration:

[image]

My installation window is not moving forward from mysql configuration screen. I am not getting any error or success message on click of install. Noting happens when i click on next screen remains same. I have added the mysql odbc driver in datasource admin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [requirements](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/windows/community/system-requirements.aspx) of Onlyoffice CommunityServer - Windows 10 is not supported.

> Software requirements
>
> OS Microsoft Windows Server 2012(R2)